# Yii search for each term in a comma-separated query string not working as expected

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I would like to accomplish searching my model by searching for each term in a query string separated by commas. For example, if the string is `"matza,red wine"` then I want to search for items matching `"matza"`and `"red%20wine"`. This is the code I am using:

```
       $qString = $_GET['q'];

       $criteria = new CDbCriteria();

       $queryTerms = explode(',', $qString);

       foreach ($queryTerms as $q) {

              $tCriteria = new CDbCriteria();

              $criteria->addSearchCondition('name', $q, true);
              $criteria->addSearchCondition('text_ingredients', $q, true, 'OR');

              $criteria->mergeWith($tCriteria);
       }

       $results = FoodItem::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

And it runs and all, but the results are not correct. For example, I would expect that searching for `"A,B"` would yield the same results as for `"B,A"`, but it does not. I wish there was a way to log or `echo` some representation of the resulting `$criteria`. I have a feeling it has something to do with the way I am using `mergeWith`.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tCriteria seems to be empty at the end of the loop. You are not merging anything.

Maybe you meant to make the two addSearchCondition lines work on tCriteria whereas you have them working on criteria.

Comment: Embarrassing. I guess that's what you get when you use poor variable names that look too much alike.